# Python / pdblp: Easiest way to pull a single historical request?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bloomberg, pdblp

I have recently started using the pdblp module documented [here](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp). However, I find myself spending a lot of time trying to just manipulate the dataframes.

For example, the following code gives:

```
import pdblp as bbg

con = bbg.BCon(port=8194, timeout=5000, debug=False)
con.debug = False
con.start()
EURUSD = con.bdh('EURUSD Curncy', 'PX_LAST', monthEnd, monthEnd)
print(EURUSD)
```

The result is

```
ticker     EURUSD Curncy
field            PX_LAST
date                    
2019-11-29        1.1018
```

However, whats the easierst way to get `EURUSD = 1.1018`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: blp.bdh('EURUSD Curncy', end_date='2019-11-30').iloc[-1, 0]
Out[2]: 1.1018
```

Reference: [xbbg](https://github.com/alpha-xone/xbbg)